# How can I achieve this position?

Tags: flexibility, yoga, lower-back, mobility

I saw this picture:

[image]

and noticed the straight upper and lower back. My hamstrings were tight, I stretched them a lot and I am able to touch the ground almost with the palms of my hands, but I think I am compensating lacking hamstring flexibility with a round spine.

Look at me doing the same stretch.

[image]

**Questions:**

- **Can you see the bend in the lower back? How can I get rid of it?**
- **How can I isolate the hamstrings so that I don't compensate with my spine?**

Comment: Instead of trying to touch the ground, you should focus on keeping your back straight and getting a good stretch in your calf and hamstring. Eventually you will get more flexible.

Comment: Avoid that stretch, focus on keeping you back straight, or put an object in between your legs and squeeze it hard and try again. Google antranik splits routine, the lower back bend comes from lack of hamstring flexilbility

Comment: I have the exact same problem, and it's effecting my bend over row form. I really can't keep my back straight.

Answer (score 2):

Are you capable of activating the muscles in your lower back? Because that's what will keep your back straight in such a position. You are basically hanging on your spine in the picture, which is especially bad when doing e.g. deadlifts, though you should avoid it here too.
Also, the point of the stretch is not to reach the ground but to provide sufficient stretch to your hamstrings so that they may become more flexible.

Comment: ok, I see but the deadlift part goes to far for this discussion.